# VF inputText field to filter a wrapper list containing custom SObject

Tags: apex, controller, content-search

I currently have a wrapper list containing custom sObjects and checkboxes. I also have a inputText field on a Visualforce page and would like to filter the wrapper list by License_Voucher__c which is a field in my custom SObject contained within my wrapper.

I would like for the search to contain all variances of the string such as if the user typed in 'john' , the search would return 'john', 'johnson', 'johnny'. Basically john* or a sql equivalent of 'LIKE'.

To make life simpler I added a string voucherNumber to my wrapper and tried to iterate through the list with the .contains() to see if each element met the inputText requirements.

Unfortunately whether I try searching with the entire correct string or part of the correct string I seem to get no results. Would there be a better approach to this? thanks!

### Wrapper Class

```
public class wrapper_OlympusLR{ 
public License_Request__c lrObj {get;set;}
public String macAddress {get;set;}
public String serverName {get;set;}
public String serialNumber {get;set;}
public String serverModel {get;set;}
public Boolean selected {get;set;}
public String voucherNumber {get;set;}

public wrapper_OlympusLR(License_Request__c lrq)
{              
        this.lrObj      = lrq;
        this.selected   = false;               
        this.macAddress = null;
        this.serverName = null;
        this.serialNumber   = null;
        this.serverModel    = null;
        this.voucherNumber = lrq.License_Voucher__c;

}
```

### Controller Search Method

```
    public PageReference runSearch()
{
    String voucherNumber = inputVoucherNumber+'.*';
    if(voucherNumber.equals(''))
    {
        //DO NOTHING OR USE ORIGINAL LIST 
        wrapDynLRList = wrapLRListOriginal;

    }
    else
    {
        wrapDynLRList.clear();
        for(wrapper_OlympusLR lrList : wrapLRListOriginal)
        {
            if(lrList.voucherNumber.contains(voucherNumber))
            {
                wrapDynLRList.add(lrList);
            }
        }

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The code you posted appears to have 3 different lists: wrapDynLRList, wrapLRListOriginal and wrapLRList. It would make more sense if wrapLRListOriginal was used in place of wrapLRList.

Comment: small typo mistake on my part. There's only supposed to be two lists and not three. Fixed it for a better understanding. Thanks for spotting that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to append the '.*' on the voucher number

Using the .contains(voucherNumber) will return any result that has the voucherNumber in the field the [contains](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_contains) is applied on.

Comment: bah, guess I overlooked how the .contains() works. Removing the .* fixed it, thanks for the insight.